# Salesforce Marketing cloud user creation error

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have an enterprise 2.0 SFMC account and while creating a new user I am facing "Invalid @MemberID. It should be of type Enterprise_2 if business unit user is to be created" error.
I have tried it with parent and child BU both.
[image: error details]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known issue. Please refer [this](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YotwQAC&title=error-message-displays-when-creating-new-user-under-business-unit-account).

Can you logout from SFMC and login again and try to create the user in Parent Business Unit.

Comment: Yes, this is also confirmed to be a known issue, and also listed on [Adam Spriggs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) blog page [SFMC Known Issues](https://sprignaturemoves.com/sfmcki.php)...visit this page and seach for `@MemberID`

Comment: I have tried it also...still not working